# Quarkus / CDI and "java config" DI definitions

Tags: cdi, quarkus

I just started a quarkus proof of concept.  The containers-start time is amazing!

Right now, I'm working on the Dependency Injection part.  And figuring out the options.

https://quarkus.io/blog/quarkus-dependency-injection/

My preferences are:

I prefer constructor injection.  (This has been going ok).

I prefer "java config" so I can follow the "Composition Root" pattern of putting all my application dependency injections in a common place.  (See https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/ )

With Spring DI, this is done with the

> org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration

and declaring the Beans there.

Aka, I prefer not to place "@ApplicationScoped" annotations all over my classes.

Does CDI/Quarkus support a "java config" model?  The reason I ask about quarkus is that I read quarkus has a limited CDI implementation.

> //start quote//Our primary goal was to implement a supersonic
>   build-time oriented DI solution compatible with CDI. This would allow
>   users to continue using CDI in their applications but also leverage
>   Quarkus build-time optimizations. However, ArC is not a full CDI
>   implementation verified by the TCK - see also the list of supported
>   features and the list of limitations.//end quote

So my question isn't a solely CDI question.

I've tried different internet search terms, but they keep showing me Spring links.  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a CDI bean that will produce your beans, this is the standard CDI approach to what Spring calls Java Configuration.

So something like this

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;


@ApplicationScoped
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Produces
    public MyBean myBean(){
        return new MyBean();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working.  Thanks.  sometimes the magic terms get confusing.

Comment: The only annotation I had to add. was @Inject on classes with more than 1 constructor. (import javax.inject.Inject;)

Comment: I edited your answer to include import statements. #petPeeve with java examples.

Comment: This seems to lead to MyBean being produces everytime it is needed, which is at least not what I intended..

Comment: @Tarnschaf the default scope of a `@Produces` is dependent so a bean will be created each time. If you want your bean to have a different scope you should annotate the producing method with one of the scope annotation, for example `@ApplicationScoped `.