# Static dependency Injection solution for Java Server Side applications?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, dagger

JavaEE offers CDI (context and dependency Injection), Spring offers dependency injection. However, both raise issues and exceptions at deployment (server startup time) regarding duplicate or missing dependencies.

Is there a dependency injection solution like Dagger (which is used for android) for server-side applications that offers full-static compile-time dependency analysis/resolution and informs the developer of the issues and errors.

Comment: Have a look into `Qwarkus`

Comment: [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/) actually, and its CDI-like dependency injection library, [ArC](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/tree/master/independent-projects/arc) (not an independent project yet).

Comment: The complains on dependencies you stated are very vague, it is hard to say what's the problem there. Otherwise, CDI might do most of what you are after except that it doesn't to it at compile time but at boot time because of extensions and other things that can affect the injection model while it is being started. It does however give you deployment errors informing the developer what injections are unsatisfied/ambiguous and so on. Quarkus uses Arc and a "partial CDI implementation" and is probably even closer to the functionality you described, but is a (sort of) different approach from ee.

Comment: IMHO, if you throw away ComponentScan or any Scanning voodoo, and go with "java config" aka "composition root" where you "code up" your DI (whether with spring-di or cdi), you'll have a lot less drama.  I call "ComponentScan" the "Where's Waldo" approach to DI, because when it isn't working, you spend hours chasing down Waldo.  SpringDI "java config" is fairly well documented.  Here is a CDI example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58544079/quarkus-cdi-and-java-config-di-definitions/58544213#58544213     here is a link about the idea of composition root (nutshell a SINGLE place to compose)

Comment: ..compose the dependency graph : https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/

Answer (score 0):

Dagger is not Android-specific, it's a general purpose Java library, same as Guava, feel free to use it server-side, alongside EE apis.

You could argue that Dagger is even more of a "general Java" solution than the likes of Spring or Weld, because it uses core mechanics of the language instead of quite complex mechanics provided by the runtime. This is exactly why it was used with great success on platforms like Android or GWT.